# Eye of the Storm and Kicker Costs

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Rite of Replication](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRite%20of%20Replication%5d) is exiled with [Eye of the Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEye%20of%20the%20Storm%5d), can people pay the kicker cost to still get 5 tokens?

Comment: I think Imprint on Isochron Scepter and copy by Eye of the Storm are sufficiently distinct to allow both questions.

Comment: @Hackworth Imprint has no actual rules meaning. And honestly, [Isochron Scepter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=413765)'s first ability (the Imprint ability) is not the subject of the other question. Isochron Scepter's second ability allows you to copy an exiled spell and then cast the copy. Eye of the Storm allows you to copy an exiled spell and then cast the copy. They seem the same to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can pay the kicker costs for the each copy if you want the extra tokens.**

Some cards copy spells on the stack directly. You cannot choose to pay kicker for those spells, the choice and additional costs are copied from the original.

In this case, however, the whole card is copied, and you may cast it as a new spell without paying its mana cost. In that case, you are free to decide whether or not to pay the kicker costs, which are additional costs and have nothing to do with the spell's mana costs:

> 702.32a Kicker is a static ability that functions while the spell with kicker is on the stack. “Kicker [cost]” means “You may pay an additional [cost] as you cast this spell.” Paying a spell’s kicker cost(s) follows the rules for paying additional costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.

Note that you may also pay the kicker costs for the original Rite, but that would be a waste of mana, because the original is exiled and does not resolve. Neither paying nor not paying the kicker on the original Rite has any effect on the copies.

Answer (score 0):

From the gatherer entry for [Eye of the Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEye%20of%20the%20Storm%5d):

> The player chooses modes, pays additional costs, chooses targets, and so on for the copies when casting them

and

> When a spell with Replicate is copied by Eye of the Storm, you have the  opportunity to pay additional costs

Replicate was used in the reminder above, as that was an additional cost mechanic in that block. Kicker follows the same rules in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Kicker.

---

The total cost to cast a spell = (mana cost or alternative cost) + (additional costs and cost increases) - cost reductions

Eye of the Storm's ability allows you to cast the spell for an alternative cost ("for free").

Kicker can be used when you cast a spell by imposing an additional cost. Nothing about casting a spell using an alternative cost prevents this.